# Code design for the multidocument tabbed interface for React SPA with react-router/react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, redux, react-router, tabs

I have React SPA application with react-router/react-router-dom navigation, that means that there is react-router-dom (additional layer for react-router) Switch statement with selects the according to the path:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage}/>
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path='/sales/orderlist' component={OrderListPage}/>
    <Route path='/sales/order' component={() => <OrderPage/>}/>
    <Route path='/sales/order/:id' component={() => <OrderPage/>}/>
    <Route path='/sales/invoicelist' component={InvoiceListPage}/>
    <Route path='/sales/invoice' component={InvoicePage}/>
    <Route path='/sales/invoice/:id' component={InvoicePage}/>
</Switch>
```

My application also has react-router Links in navigation bar, so - that is the way how simple navigation works. I understand that execution of the link '/sales/invoice/58' does the following 3 things:

1. It instantiates the InvoicePage component;
2. It moves the id value 58 to the props of InvoicePage;
3. It makes the instantiated component (effectively  element with large content) visible and all the remaining instantiated components (if any, e.g. InvoiceListPage) (which are just  elements/DOM trees with large content themselves) visible=false. *I am not sure whether such out-navigation releases components, my guess is, that they stays in the memory (in the DOM tree). I am also not sure what happens when 2 consecutive calls 'sales/invoice/59' and 'sales/invoice/60' are made - is only one InvoicePage component instantiated and then its props attribute is changed from 59 to 60 (which may or may not trigger the full or partial data reload according to the business logic coded in that component)? Or maybe react-router assures that two different calls with two different id-values creates two different components?* *(these mini-questions are not questions in the sense of SO question that should be answered - I am just babbling here and I am listing the points for consideration in the question format, these are not real SO questions)*

My question is - **how can I make this design into multi-tab multi-document design?** My application should sit into one page/tab of browser and my application shoud have application-level tabs. E.g. when user presses the link to the InvoiceList, then new application tab with InvoiceList report opens. When user selects one definite invoice and this report and click to linke then another application tab with Invoice (with specific Id) opens. And user can open many tabs with different invoices.

What is the design, ideas for such multi-tabbed multi-document interface? It should be pretty hard and confusing to create one. E.g. standard react-router displays #-link to the active component in the browser url field. But if my SPA application has multiple open/active application level tabs with multiple-open React components/documents - then what link the browser should display?

And what about Redux support - usually application has one application wide Redux store, but now - each component (InvoiceListPage, InvoicePage, OrderPage) should have their own Redux stores - i.e. Redux store should be implemented as the array and whole SPA application should keep some records - which compoent to which element of the Redux array belongs...

Just wanted to know about the general design of multi-tab multi-document interface with react-router for React SPA application for the web.

Such multi-tab GUI is quite common - e.g. Metasfresh https://github.com/metasfresh/metasfresh have one, Lotus Notes has one, multi-tab interface is the preferred organization of multi-document interface for the Microsoft WPF (at least it was when I read about it some time ago).

Answer (score 1):

In reactJS you have local state (this.state or useState) you have state passed from parent components (called props), you have state passed by ancestor components (called context) you may have state from other parts of the app (redux for instance). But all of these, are just "state", based on which you render what do you want to see on the screen.

So what is MDI effectively? It is a list of open documents (so you need to have somewhere in your state such a list of open documents, each element of which sould represent the present state of that particular document), and a currently open document which should be somewhere in your state. In your example, the state that tells you which one is the currently open document is... react-router's location!

So you could use redux (or create your own store) and hold somewhere the open documents

```js
//store's instance
{
   ...,
   openDocuments:[
       { path: '/sales/invoice/1', title: 'Invoice #1', ... },
       { path: '/sales/invoice/2', title: 'Invoice #2', ... },
       { path: '/sales/order/13', title: 'Order #13', ... }
   ],
   ...
}
// The 'path' property of each openDocument serves as the id of that document
// and should be unique in the array
```

Then in your layout you should have a tabbed navigation bar that would render each item as a tab and probably highlight the active tab (by using the useMatch hook to check if page location matches the id of that particular item).

In the middle of your layout you should have your regular `<Switch />` that would render the actual page based on react router's location.
You could also create some hooks like `useCurrentDocumentState` to read the state of the currently open document. (*In that hook for example you would read from your store, find the item in the array that corresponds to the actual open document and return it*)

Actually, if you think of it, the usual Single Page Application with the nav bar on the left (menu items) is just a kind of Multi Document Interface where all menu items are considered to be "opened" but only focused when you click on them.

You shouldn't actually care what happens in the DOM and wether your tabs stay open but hidden or removed from DOM. It's react's business to take care of the DOM, and actually this is one of the reasons it was built for. So that you don't bother about the DOM. You should only bother of what kind of information **you** want to hold open for each tab (the tabs' state) in the lifetime of the application.